# ViewTransitions break inView animation (Motion One)

Tags: javascript, astrojs, view-transitions-api

I'm using ViewTransitions to fade between pages and use motion ones inView animation on headings to fade them in. They only work on the first page load.

This is what i tried:

```
<script>
      import { animate, inView } from 'motion';

      const doFadeIn = (target: Element) =>
        animate(
          target,
          {
            opacity: [0, 1],
            transform: ['translateX(-10px)', 'translateX(10px)'],
          },
          { duration: 0.5, delay: 0.1 }
        );

      inView('h2', (el) => {
        doFadeIn(el.target);
      });
</script>
```

and the ViewTransition is from Astro

```html
<html transition:animate="fade">
  <head>
    <title> My Page </title>
    <ViewTransitions />
  </head>
</html>
```

On The first page load it works as expected but after navigating, the inView doesn't trigger anymore.